# How can I change my bash prompt to show my working directory?

Tags: bash, osx, prompt

I can print my current working dir like this

```
myPrompt$ pwd
/Users/me/myDir
```

I want my shell to look like this

```
/Users/me/myDir$ pwd
/Users/me/myDir
```

Is that possible? How can I do it?

Comment: On OS X the name of the file is .bash_profile not just .profile. That will autoload for you.

Comment: Not quite. OSX [starts login shells](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/) by default and that means that bash looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in  that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. In any case, this is really a comment and not an answer so I am converting it to one.

Comment: If you came here looking for a way to do the *opposite* (i.e. stop showing working directory) you'll want `PS1='\$ '`

Answer (score 83):

You can use [escape sequences](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Controlling-the-Prompt) in prompt [variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bourne-Shell-Variables).

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
PS1='\w\$ '
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a one-liner for OSX. It appends the prompt you want into the profile file and then reloads the profile.

```
echo "PS1='\w\$ '" >> ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile
```

On El Capitan you'll want to use

```
echo "PS1='\w\$ '" >> ~/.profile; source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 3):

For some reason `'\w\$'` didn't work for me but instead I did: `export PS1="$(pwd) \$"` and it worked.

Comment: That won’t work too well when you change directories...

Comment: @StephenKitt, did you bother to try it? I tried and it works with directory change. Can't believe you have 8 upvotes for the comment.

Comment: @PAS yes, I did. The prompt gets set to whatever the current directory is when the `export` command is run, and doesn’t change when the current directory changes.

Comment: I am not seeing these results. I can see directory changing. here is my test  can't put new lines here...

`/c/Program Files$ cd /c/temp/

/c/temp$ cd /c/Program\ Files

/c/Program Files$ cd /c/temp/

/c/temp$ cd /c/Program\ Files
Program Files/       Program Files (x86)/

/c/temp$ cd /c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/

/c/Program Files (x86)$`

Comment: @StephenKitt can you double check if your synatx is correct
`PS1="$PS1"'$(pwd)'                 # current working directory`

Comment: @PAS that’s not what the answer says. I was commenting on the answer, not some putative corrected variant.

Comment: @StephenKitt, you said "That won’t work too well when you change directories". This is not true on my machine using git bash.

Comment: @PAS using `export PS1="$(pwd) \$"`, or `PS1="$PS1"'$(pwd)'`?

Comment: I am not using export. It's directly in C:\Users\mylogin\.config\git\git-prompt.sh
do you have any profile file where you can put this instead of export? 
I do agree, exporting is a bad idea for this but the answer is valuable as $(pwd) is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like an old thread but the steps below worked for me on OS X 10.9.5

- put `PS1='\w\$ '` in `~/.profile`
- if you made any changes in `~/.bashrc` remove them
- close the terminal with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>
- reopen the terminal

Comment: In my case the complete PATH is really big so I have added one more flag for next line like PS1='\w\n\$ '

Answer (score 1):

**For Python and Conda Users:**

Add the following line to `~/.bashrc` and run `source ~/.bashrc` after saving it.
The following will show conda environment, username, device name, and base of current working directory.
Additionally, it is colored cyan.

```bsh
PS1="\e[0;36m ($CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV) \u@\h \W → \e[m "
```

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion

Put this in your ~/.bashrc:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\](\D{%H:%M:%S})\[\033[01;34m\]:$PWD\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

This will color line, and will also add time on every line (Time can be useful some time)

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution**

Open `~/.bash_profile` and add the following content

```
# \[\e[0m\] resets the color to default color
reset_color='\[\e[0m\]'
#  \[\033[33m\] sets the color to yellow
path_color='\[\033[33m\]'
# \e[0;32m\ sets the color to green
git_clean_color='\[\e[0;32m\]'
# \e[0;31m\ sets the color to red
git_dirty_color='\[\e[0;31m\]'

# determines if the git branch you are on is clean or dirty
git_prompt ()
{
  # Is this a git directory?
  if ! git rev-parse --git-dir > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    return 0
  fi
  # Grab working branch name
  git_branch=$(git branch 2>/dev/null| sed -n '/^\*/s/^\* //p')
  # Clean or dirty branch
  if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2; then
    git_color="${git_clean_color}"
  else
    git_color="${git_dirty_color}"
  fi
  echo " [$git_color$git_branch${reset_color}]"
}

export PS1="${path_color}\w\[\e[0m\]$(git_prompt)\n"
```

This should:

```
1) Prompt the path you're in, in color: path_color.
2) Tell you which branch are you.
3) Color the name of the branch based on the status of the branch with git_clean_color 
for a clean work directory and git_dirty_color for a dirty one.
4) The brackets should stay in the default color you established in your computer.
5) Puts the prompt in the next line for readability.
```

You can customize the colors with this [list](https://github.com/ryanoasis/public-bash-scripts/blob/master/unix-color-codes.sh)

**Sophisticated Solution**

Another option is to use Git Bash Prompt, install with [this](https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt#installation). I used the option via Homebrew on Mac OS X.

`git_prompt_list_themes` to see the themes but I didn't like any of them.

`git_prompt_color_samples` to see available colors.

`git_prompt_make_custom_theme [<Name of base theme>]` to create a new custom theme, this should create a .git-prompt-colors.sh file.

`subl ~/.git-prompt-colors.sh` to open git-prompt-colors.sh and customize:

The .git-prompt-colors.sh file should look like this with my customization

```
    override_git_prompt_colors() {
      GIT_PROMPT_THEME_NAME="Custom"

      # Clean or dirty branch
      if git diff --quiet 2>/dev/null >&2; then
        GIT_PROMPT_BRANCH="${Green}"
      else
        GIT_PROMPT_BRANCH="${Red}"
      fi
    }

    reload_git_prompt_colors "Custom"
```

This answer is based on my SO answer which you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333531/how-can-i-display-the-current-branch-and-folder-path-in-terminal/55717132#55717132). Hope this helps, have a great day!

Comment: I think the OP was intending to simply display the _shell's_ working directory. As a regular Git user I'm also using some fancy Git-aware prompt but that seems to be overkill here.