# Remove line that calls "composer" from bash file

Tags: bash, bashrc

When I run composer I get this

```
bash: /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer: No such file or directory
```

I'm trying to find where my bash profile (the file that contains my PATH is.  I'm on Centos 6.
I run: `nano /root/.bashrc` and there's no entry in there
I run `/etc/bashrc` same no entry.
I've checked online and can't find any answer pointing me to where it would be.

Per comments I've tried:  `/etc/profile and $HOME/.profile`
I need to remove that composer path, wherever that file is.

Comment: Are you trying to find where `bash` is, or where `composer` is?

Comment: bash so I can remove that line about composer.  I need to reinstall it @SaswatPadhi

Comment: Have you tried running `which bash` on your system?

Comment: I think you mean `.bashrc` or `.profile` instead of `bash`. You can't really "remove  a line from `bash`" ...
Check `/etc/profile` and `$HOME/.profile` files

Comment: I do I get /bin/bash but when I nano this it has a bunch of blob looking code.  I need the file where I can edit that's why I thought .bashrc was the file.  @SaswatPadhi

Comment: Neither /etc/profile nor $HOME/.profile contain the file.  @SaswatPadhi

Comment: Also see this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/334389/360388

Answer (score 1):

Per Saswati in comments.
I ran:

```
echo exit | strace bash -li |& less | grep '^open'
```

Here I was able to see that cpanel was generating the export here:

```
open("/etc/profile.d/cpanel-php-composer.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

I then uncommented it from the above.