# Where is the EDITOR env variable originally set?

Tags: bash, fedora, environment-variables

Where is the EDITOR environment variable initialized? so far I have checked the following files and could not find where it is:

- ~/.bashrc
- ~/.bash_profile
- ~/.profile
- /etc/profile
- /etc/bashrc
- /etc/environment

Comment: What do you mean by "originally"? By default it's **not** set at all.

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere. You are thinking about it from a wrong perspective.

Each application has its own preferred editor (or pager, or whatever else it needs). That is *built in* into application. Defined at compile time and never changes.

If creator of application *wants* to allow user to change it later - then an application can take a look at environment variable EDITOR, PAGER, etc and use whatever user defined there.

Some applications with capability to switch to a user preferred editor do not look at environment variable EDITOR, but at its own configuration files. Or both (`git` for example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that $EDITOR is set in your current shell but you are not sure how and where it got set? If that's the case, and you are on a system with `strace` installed like Linux you may want to try to look at all the files that BASH for instance opens. I modified the answer in this question slightly [Find out what scripts are being run by bash at login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/334382/find-out-what-scripts-are-being-run-by-bash-at-login/334389#334389)

`echo exit | strace -e open bash -li`

From the BASH man page:

```
      -i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
       -l        Make bash act as if it had been invoked as a login shell (see INVOCATION below).
```

Another way, in another comment from that answer is to invoke bash with the `-x` flag enabling echo of each command that is executed:

```
/bin/bash -x -l -i -c 'exit' 2>&1 | less
```

I would do this first to make sure that $EDITOR is somehow even being set on startup and not exported by some other script or program you are running after your shell has already initialized.