# Why does my bash terminal startup run the same set of commands twice?

Tags: bash, terminal, java, startup, bashrc

I'm on a Mac and whenever I start up my terminal app the initial startup prints the following:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:MaxPermSize=4G -Xmx4G
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=4G; support was removed in 8.0
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -XX:MaxPermSize=4G -Xmx4G
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=4G; support was removed in 8.0
java version "1.8.0_112"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b16)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b16, mixed mode)
```

It seems to be loading Java twice and I'm not sure why. I thought this was coming from my ~/.bash_profile file but I can't seem to find what is doing it. This is what is contained in my `bash_profile`:

```
export AD_USERNAME=myfirstname.mylastname
    yodle_dev_include_repo_prompt=1
    source $HOME/.dev-shell-utils/conf/sh/all
    export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
    if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi

    # Instead of modifying your local .bash_profile, consider updating dev-shell-utils instead.
    # TODO: Move the following into dev-shell-utils.

    removeFromPath ()
    {
        export PATH=$(echo $PATH | sed -E -e "s;:$1;;" -e "s;$1:?;;")
    }

    setHaProxyAlias ()
    {
        sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 172.17.32.1
    }

setjdk 1.8
    # Prefer Homebrew installed utils
    PATH=$PATH:$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnubin
    MANPATH=$(brew --prefix coreutils)/libexec/gnuman:$MANPATH

    PATH=$PATH:/workspace/src/core/ThriftTools/Thrift/bin

export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxBxDxCxegedabagacad
alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

Thought it might be my `bashrc` file but it seems like all that is doing is setting some aliases and environment variables.

```
alias readlink="greadlink"
alias jbossrun="sudo /usr/local/jboss/bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -DSERVICE_DISCOVERY=true"
export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:MaxPermSize=4G -Xmx4G"
export JBOSS_HOME=/usr/local/jboss
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this double print-out when I start up my bash terminal? I'm using [Hyper](https://hyper.is/) but this happens with the default Mac terminal app and iTerm as well.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is the `source $HOME/.dev-shell-utils/conf/sh/all` line, so what is in that file? If you run `setjdk 1.8` as a command do you get these lines output?

Comment: Have you tried running `. ~/.profile`, `~/.bash_profile`, `. ~/.bashrc`, and `./.bash_aliases`?

Comment: Your indenting is all over the place. It makes it hard to read.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` isn't read by interactive shells on macOS since they seem to [always start login shells by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/22222).

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the code that you show prints any of the output that you shows, so it must be coming from some part that you don't show.

You should be able to find the culprit by yourself, or at least to isolate a small, problematic part, with the following information:

- On macOS, each terminal opens a login shell by default.
- When bash is started as a login shell, it executes commands from `~/.bash_profile`.
- Put `set -x` at the top of `.bash_profile` and bash will print a trace of each command just before it executes it. It'll look like this:

  ```
  + export AD_USERNAME=myfirstname.mylastname
  + AD_USERNAME=myfirstname.mylastname
  + yodle_dev_include_repo_prompt=1
  + source /home/intA/.dev-shell-utils/conf/sh/all
  …
  ```

  So check which commands(s) print this unwanted output.