# Issues with systemctl on macOS

Tags: zsh, path, macos, systemctl

I have moved to `zsh` in the course of an upgrade. However, now I'm trying to issue some `systemctl` commands but keep getting "command not found" errors.

My `~/.bashrc` file:

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
```

The top of my `~/.zshrc`:

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
# export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:$PATH
  export PATH="$PATH:$HOME"

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="/Users/<username>/.oh-my-zsh"
```

Have been banging my head against the wall on this !! - I've tried all the paths already commented out.

Comment: systemctl? On macOS?

Comment: yes ? maybe thats whats wrong? FML

Comment: Note that `~/.bashrc` is irrelevant if you're using zsh. In fact, it's not relevant on macOS in general since it [starts login shells by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/22222).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Fox.

Had to use

```
sudo launchctl start|stop postfix
```