# Set an environment variable per user shell independent

Tags: shell, users, environment-variables

How can I set an permanent environment variable per user independent from the used shell (`bash`, `zsh` and `fish`)?

Comment: not sure I understood, but if you want to set an environment variable for all shells, you can put it in `~/.profile` (for one user) or `/etc/profile` (for all users)

Comment: bash doesn't read ~/.profile, only /etc/profile.

Comment: then, you could, in `/etc/profile` add a `source $HOME/.custom-profile`, and use that (though it's a bit hacky)

Comment: @MarcusMüller bash does read `.profile` when started as a login shell. The exception is only if _you_ or your sysadmin have created a `~/.bash_profile` file. Then, but only then, bash will skip `~/.profile` and read that one instead.

Comment: @terdon didn't see that in `man bash`! Good to know.

Comment: @MarcusMüller see the "INVOCATION" section in `man bash`, also reproduced in this question: [Why are interactive shells on OSX login shells by default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627)

Comment: @terdon, indeed, there it is!

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: according to [What's the best distro/shell-agnostic way to set environment variables?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88201/whats-the-best-distro-shell-agnostic-way-to-set-environment-variables), the best solution for this is `~/.pam_environment`

EDIT: reverted to the hacky solution since `~/.profile` is not read by all shells:

All shells source `/etc/profile`.

That means in `/etc/profile`, you could put a line like

```bsh
. $HOME/.custom-profile
```

Then, you could add your variables to `~/.custom-profile` for each user

Comment: You are just recreating the existing functionality. This is what `~/.profile` is for. If a shell reads `/etc/profile`, it will also read `~/.profile`.

Comment: yep, I was misguided by the comment telling that bash didn't read `~/.profile`, editing

Comment: The `zsh` shell does not read `~/.profile` by default, and neither does the `fish` shell.

Comment: @terdon `zsh` only reads `/etc/profile` if it's started in `sh` or `ksh` compatibility mode. The `fish` shell does not to my knowledge read `/etc/profile`.

Comment: ok reverting to previous answer

Comment: Note that `source` is a built in utility in _some_ shells. The POSIX equivalent is `.` (dot). Fish has `source` too, but it's unclear whether any _other_ command in `/etc/profile` would understood by that shell.

Comment: I changed `source` to `.`, though, do you have an example of shell that doesn't understand `source`?

Comment: @Kusalananda Seriously? Wow. My apologies, Nephanth, I stand corrected.

Comment: @terdon No problem, I was unaware too

Answer (score 0):

All shells read different per-user profile files (zsh: ~/.profile, bash: ~/.bash_profile, csh has only an rc file, and so on). So you'd have to change all of these potential candidates.

However, most shells at the very least fall back to reading ~/.profile (thanks @terdon for pointing this out!), so that's where you can put your exports.

Since "logging in" is usually done by a process having the ability to change its uid and gid (typically: a login manager runnning as root), it's up to these programs to define the environment for the spawned program (e.g. a shell).

But: there's more than one login manager (your GDM/lightdm/KDM/... visual login manager, getty, logind/loginct, ssh, getty...), and they read configuration from different files, so there's no consistent way there, either.