# python virtualenv activation in bashrc causes environment variables to be overwritten

Tags: bash, environment-variables, path

I have a virtual environment which I usually activate by default in my bashrc via `source ~/.venv/env/bin/activate`. This has been working fine on an old MacBook Air and Linux Desktops and servers (I use the same bashrc with some different conditional blocks for each  machine)

I just got a new MacBook and I was setting everything up and I found that when calling the `activate` command above, my $PATH environment variable gets overwritten which messes up everything that was added to it before. The only line I can see in activate which modifies the path is below, but I cannot see why it would be overwriting it. Any ideas?

```
_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

Comment: Could this be linked to the fact that macs now have zsh as the default shell? Where is your PATH being set? Is it in `~/.bashrc` or in `~/.profile` or somewhere else? Also, Macs [used to launch login shells by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/22222), at least before switching to zsh, which means they don't read bashrc. Is that still the case? Try adding some `echo "P:$PATH"` statements in the various startup files to see if you can track it down.

Comment: I have the shell switched to bash in the preferences because I have too many machines working off of the same base files and I didn't want to take the time to learn a new shell. I was setting some $PATH variables in both `.bashrc` and `.profile` due to recommendations of different tools. this particular code is running in `.bashrc` so I can be sure it is running and I have narrowed it down to directly before and after the sourcing of the python environment. Before sourcing, everything in the path is correct.

Comment: OK, thanks. Could you add some of that detail to your question so the next person won't wonder about it? Ideally, show us a minimal example that reproduces what you see. Maybe you aren't `export`ing `PATH` in bashrc? Is the `_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH` variable what you expect? Where exactly does it change? You'll need to echo the contents of `PATH` at various times to see precisely which command is resetting it.