# Problem with .bashrc when I use anima command

Tags: bash, command-not-found

I need to use the Anima command without having to write the entire path every time.
I cannot use animaConvertImage in on an internal file in a folder other than the one where the Anima commands are located.
I'm using macOS in a mac with M1 processor.
I tried using the .bashrc file, but to no avail, specifically:

-I added the following lines to the `~/.bashrc` file in the following way:

`gedit ~/.bashrc &`

And added:

```
ANIMAHOME=~/Software/Anima/build

export PATH=$ANIMAHOME/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ANIMAHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

(I did it following a guide but i don't know how it should work; the Anima file included animaConvertImage are located in `/Software/Anima/build/bin`. )

Finally I saved and closed the terminal to make the changes active.

Then I used the command:

```
animaConvertImage -i dwi/Noddi_Combined_Tensors_final.nrrd -I
```

With dwi folder external to the Software folder I always get as output:

`-bash: animaConvertImage: command not found`

How can I solve the problem? (I'm not sure if the two are connected to each other since I'm a beginner)

In order to give you more information I ran the following commands:

```
$ ls -l ~/Software/Anima/build/bin/animaConvertImage
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lorenzomarta staff 3807134 14 Feb 16:07 /Users/lorenzomarta/Software/Anima/build/bin/animaConvertImage
```

and

```
$ ps -p $$
 PID TTY           TIME CMD
 3889 ttys000    0:00.08 -bash
```

Comment: Are those really the lines you added? Do you really all those spaces? For example, is it really `ANIMAHOME = ~ / Software / Anima / build` or did you mean `ANIMAHOME=~/Software/Anima/build`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make sure you show us _exactly_ what you put in the file.  Use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format code as code for clarity. Next, tell us if you saved the file or just "closed the terminal" and, finally, show us the output of `ls -l ~/Software/Anima/build/animaConvertImage`. You seem to be expecting to find an executable file named `animaConvertImage` in the directory `~/Software/Anima/build/` and the output of the `ls` command will show us if it actually exists there or not.

Comment: Please ***EDIT*** your question to answer comments. As you can see, comments are very hard to read. Also, please tell us your operating system. Are you using macOS? What version? Are you using `bash` or `zsh`? `~/.bashrc` is not really relevant to macOS since newer versions have switched to `zsh` instead of `bash` and even older versions which did use `bash` [wouldn't read `~/.bashrc`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/22222).

Comment: Please ***[EDIT]*** your question and add the output there so we can read it. And yes, you are using a mac machine, OK, but what operating system? Is it macOS or have you installed a Linux on it? Finally, please clarify what shell you are using. If you don't know, just [edit] your question and include the output of `ps -p $$`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I hope the problem is clearer now

Comment: Excellent, thank you! One last test: try adding those exact lines you added to `~/.bashrc` but add them to `~/.profile` instead. Then open a new terminal and try running `animaConvertImage` again, does that work?

Comment: Same output:  `-bash: animaConvertImage: command not found`

Comment: Do you have a file named `~/.bash_profile`? What is the output of `ls ~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: The output is `/Users/lorenzomarta/.bash_profile`

Comment: Ah! OK, then undo the changes from `~/.profile` and add them to `~/.bash_profile` instead. Does that make it work?

Comment: You saved me!!! Thank you very much

Comment: great! I'll write up an answer explaining the details.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main categories of interactive bash (and others) shell: [login and non-login shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/22222). The main difference between the two is what files are read when the shell is launched, but please see the link above for details. Unlike most *nix systems, macOS [will launch login shells by default](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119627/22222). This is why you see `-bash` instead of `bash` in the output of `ps -p $$`.

Login shells do not read `~/.bashrc` but instead read `~/.bash_profile` (if present) or else `~/.profile` (and some other files as well all of which are explained in the first link above). So the changes you made to `~/.bashrc` were ignored because the shell you are running is a login shell.

So, instead of editing `~/.bashrc`, you should edit `~/.bash_profile` if that exists or, if it doesn't, edit `~/.profile`. The lines are correct but you were simply editing the wrong file.